# Correct Response for XML-RPC bad credentials

Tags: xml-rpc

I was tasked with implementing an XML-RPC service for our system and me and the project lead are bumping heads on a point, and I'm looking for some clarification/a link to the spec where this may be mentioned.

What is the best-practice in terms of a response if someone tries to access the service with incorrect username/password? From my limited experience with XML-RPC and RESTFUL services I would expect a HTTP response 401. However the project architect believes that the correct approach would be to return an XMLRPC fault response.

This approach would provide me with some difficulty as their is a security filter on the system which deals with authorisation before it even hits the XML-RPC implementation, which returns the 401. I would have to ski through this filter and deal with the authentication myself, which seems silly.

So yeah, I don't want to go down one route or the other too far and then find out the spec/best practice dictates the other option. So if someone with more experience in this topic could let me know or point me to where I can find it in the spec I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Not a duplicate, really, but there is some related discussion in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891554/xml-rpc-authentication-http-vs-xmlrpcnotauthorizedexception

Comment: Ah. So that seems to suggest that it should always return 200? Is it wrong to fail-fast with the authentication? Should i let it get to the xml-rpc engine for it to return a fault?

Comment: That does suggest to let it get to the xml-rpc engine and have the fault returned. But I agree (with you and the participants in that other thread) that that does feel a bit... wrong.